# Find the centroid of a 3D polygon

Tags: geometry

I have a 3-dimensional polygon with 3 vertices:

```
v1 = (0, 0, 0)
v2 = (0, 1, 1)
v3 = (2, 0, 2)
```

How can I find the centroid of this shape? My math is not that good, so understanding the solution for the simple example I've provided would be very helpful. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how you might tackle the problem? Have you tried finding centroids of other solids? Do you know of any techniques you can use?

Comment: Well, I think for a recangle in 2D, I could find the mid-point of the length and height, then the x, y midpoint would be the centroid. Is this correct?

Comment: If you draw your shape on paper you get a triangle with the sides $\sqrt2,\sqrt8,\sqrt5$. If you imagine this as a 2d shape you can find the mid point. The trick then is to convert that to the 3d coordinate system.

Comment: For a triangle the centroid is always always at $(v_1+v_2+v_3)/3$ no matter how many dimensions it's embedded in. Same goes for any simplex: its centroid is the mean of its vertices.

Comment: Given that the polygon in the question is a triangle, and that the one answer (which is accepted) only answers the question in regard to triangles, it would be helpful if the title reflected the narrow topic, instead of the more general question about polygons. That way, those who are searching for answers to the more general question won't be misled by the title of this question, and waste their time only to find that the general question is not addressed.

Comment: Please fix the title - one more disappointed reader who clicked this question expecting an answer for the general case (a polygon)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the equation of the line for two of the medians, and compute the intersection.

The line from $v_1$ to the midpoint of the opposite side can be parametrized by:

$$(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)+t(2,1,3)$$

The line from $v_2$ to the midpoint of the opposite side can be parametrized by:

$$(x,y,z)=(0,1,1)+s(1,-1,0)$$

This gives us the system of equations:

$$x=2t=s\\y=t=1-s\\z=3t=1$$

So we see that $t=\frac{1}{3}$ and $s=\frac{2}{3}$ is the intersection, which gives the point $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},1)$ as the centroid.

Comment: Erhm.. How do you explain that your centroid is outside of the triangle at all?

Comment: @KromStern: That is explained by the fact that I made a mistake.  It has been corrected.  Thanks!